# How to make bootstrap Modal with custom (layout & form) components

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, forms, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am making a custom Bootstrap Modal include some form components like select Tag and buttons and I am still learning.

**here is what I made so far:**
[find here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECETb.png)

**code:**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
   Launch demo modal
   </button>

<!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">CUSTOM LINK MAKER</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5>Here you can make a custom link to send.</h5>
                    <small>(All custom links will stay active) </small>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**What I trying to achieve:** [find here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHDoH.png)

Problem: I am facing a problem with setting-up layout.I don't know how to code for layout and add form components in Modal. if anyone could suggest it would be great help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to get you started:

Codepen to display example: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/MLpWrb

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
 Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">CUSTOM LINK MAKER</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddress">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddress2">Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputCity">City</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputState">State</label>
          <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            <option>...</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="inputZip">Zip</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
            Check me out
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```